# Compare current iteration with previous one, MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix, struct, constraints

How can I compare the current iteration in a loop with the previous one?

For example, I want to see if an element in the matrix, which is part of a structure, is lower than that same element, but from the previous iteration (obviously these aren't the same values, but the same elements, just different iterations). To be more clear, I need to call matrix element `mystruct(h).field(j,1)` and see if that element is lower than `mystruct(h-1).field(j,1)`.

```
a=rand(20,1);
field = 'field';
for h=1:20
    value = 1.4*rand(20,1);
    value1 = zeros(20,1);
    mystruct(h) = struct(field,value);
    NEWstruct(h) = struct(field,value1);
end

for j=1:20
    if mystruct(1).field(j,1)<a(j,1)
        NEWstruct(1).field(j,1)=mystruct(1).field(j,1);
    else
        NEWstruct(1).field(j,1)=a(j,1);
    end
end
```

Now after this I have to see if next iteration `mystruct(2).field(j,1)` is lower than previous iteration `NEWstruct(1).field(j,1)`, and if it is, assign it's value to `NEWstruct(2).field(j,1)`. If it's not, then it should be equal to `mystruct(1).field(j,1)`

Comment: Please reformat your question and post a minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a general case, you can use the following array:

```
field_data = cat(3,mystruct.field);

greater = diff(field_data, [], 3)>0;
```

Now `greater` is a 3D array made of 2D arrays of the size of `field` and `size(mystruct)-1` layers. Each layer corresponds to a change in each iteration. Thus, you have either `1` if the value has increased or `0` if it has decreased. For instance you may have something like this:

```
field_data(:,:,1) =

    0.0358    0.4735    0.6074
    0.1759    0.1527    0.1917
    0.7218    0.3411    0.7384


field_data(:,:,2) =

    0.2428    0.7655    0.0911
    0.9174    0.1887    0.5762
    0.2691    0.2875    0.6834


field_data(:,:,3) =

    0.5466    0.6476    0.9452
    0.4257    0.6790    0.2089
    0.6444    0.6358    0.7093


greater(:,:,1) =

     1     1     0
     1     1     1
     0     0     0


greater(:,:,2) =

     1     0     1
     0     1     0
     1     1     1
```

With this array you only need to check the proper value for each possible change.

In the your particular case,  if all what you want is to assign the minimum `min(mystuct(h-1).field(j),mystuct(h).field(j))` to `NEWsctruct(h).field(j)` you can simply iterate over all the values adding the following code:

```
for h=2:length(mystruct)
    for j=1:20
        NEWstruct(h).field(j) = min(mystruct(h-1).field(j),mystruct(h).field(j));
    end
end
```

Or using the vectorized form:

```
field_data = cat(2,mystruct.field);           % Gather the whole data in a matrix
minimum = min(field_data(:,2:end),field_data(:,1:end-1));  % Get the proper values (as a matrix)
NEWstruct(2:end) = cell2struct(num2cell(minimum,1),field,1);  % Assign the values to the struct
```

Comment: thank you for answer @josoler . I edited my code so it doesn't compare to 0 all the time. Now it's comparing to that value only for the first iteration. Now after this I have to see if next iteration `mystruct(2).field(j,1)` is lower than previous iteration `NEWstruct(1).field(j,1)`, and if it is, assign it's value to `NEWstruct(2).field(j,1)`. If it's not, then it should be equal to `mystruct(1).field(j,1)`. Is it possible to do that with if loop?

Comment: I thought you wanted to compare `mystruct(2).field(j,1)` with `mystruct(1).field(j,1)` rather than with `NEWstruct(1).field(j,1)`. Just to be clear: what you want is to assign to `NEWstruct(i).field(j)` the minimum of two numbers? In that case, these numbers are `mystruct(i-1).field(j)` and `mystruct(i).field(j)`? Notice that, since you are wowrking with column vectors, `field(j,1)` is the same that `field(j)`

Comment: I have edited the answer in case both answers to these questions are yes

Comment: thank you again @josoler for everything. First solution in the edited answer (for loop) worked for me :)